# CSS animations, slide in on 'block' and out on 'none'

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm building something that is using the css slide animation to have some text slide in when the text display is set to "block", but I was wondering how I would go about doing the reverse (sliding it out) when it is set to "none"? Is it possible to slide in and slide out with CSS animations, or would I have to use Javascript?

Hope that makes sense! Let me know if you have any questions!

JSfiddle of give you a better idea https://jsfiddle.net/qjwqL236/

Thanks!

And code below:

```js
document.getElementById("in-button").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("text-container").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("out-button").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("text-container").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#text-container{
  height: 30px;
  width:300px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
  display:none;
  
  position: relative;
  left: -300px;
  animation: slide 0.5sforwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#in-button{
  float:left;
 }
 
#out-button{
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<button id="in-button">
Make Div slide in
</button>

<button id="out-button">
Make Div slide out?
</button>

<br>
<br>

<div id="text-container">
  This is some text in a div.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case. It's easier to use transition than animation. This is how it works.

Everytime the button is click. It changes the value of the left property.

```
<button id="in-button">
Make Div slide in
</button>

<button id="out-button">
Make Div slide out?
</button>

<br>
<br>

<div id="text-container">
  This is some text in a div.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#text-container{
  height: 30px;
  width:300px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  left: -400px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear
}

#in-button, #out-button{
  float:left;
}
```

JS

```
var tC = document.getElementById('text-container');

document.getElementById("in-button").onclick = function(){
    tC.style.left = '0';
}

document.getElementById("out-button").onclick = function(){
    tC.style.left = '-400px';
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjwqL236/1/

Comment: If it helped you. Pick it as the right answer so, if someone going to find something similar. It can help them also. Welcome tho.

Answer (score 2):

You should use css translate because it's more performant than positioning and then you need an animation in and an animation out that you can trigger with a class change instead of the display property.

```js
document.getElementById("in-button").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("text-container").className = "in";
}

document.getElementById("out-button").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("text-container").className = "out";
}
```

```css
#text-container{
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(-310px);
}

#text-container.in {
  animation: in 0.5s both;
  -webkit-animation: in 0.5s both;
}

#text-container.out {
  animation: out 0.5s both;
  -webkit-animation: out 0.5s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes in {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-310px);
  }
}
@keyframes out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-310px);
  }
}

#in-button{
  float:left;
 }
 
#out-button{
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<button id="in-button">
Make Div slide in
</button>

<button id="out-button">
Make Div slide out?
</button>

<br>
<br>

<div id="text-container">
  This is some text in a div.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, good to know I can achieve the result with css animations as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do using animations. You need to create a `slide-out` animation just like you have a `slide-in`.

Note that it won't slide in/out automatically when you change the `display` to `none` or `block`.

```js
document.getElementById("in-button").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("text-container").setAttribute('class', 'slide-in');
}

document.getElementById("out-button").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("text-container").setAttribute('class', 'slide-out');
}
```

```css
#text-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -300px;
}
.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}
.slide-out {
  animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300px;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300px;
  }
}
#in-button {
  float: left;
}
#out-button {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button id="in-button">
  Make Div slide in
</button>

<button id="out-button">
  Make Div slide out?
</button>

<br>
<br>

<div id="text-container">
  This is some text in a div.
</div>
```

Comment: This is also good solution. However, if he decided to put another class on #text-container with a style on it. It will affect the UI. So he should concatenate the classes. And also remove class individually. In that case. He need to use indexOf to remove class and it will waste his time.

Comment: yes, I agree with you... using simple transitions is the best way